# Convoluted Date Lookup

Tags: microsoft-excel, date, vlookup

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11232210/excel-vba-code-to-search-for-value-in-colmn-that-matches-another-column-and-a-da), which is pretty close, but I don't know VB, so I'm trying to do this with a vanilla formula.

First worksheet has a series of tables of unemployment rate: 1 per US state. Each table presents data with year as row label, month as column label, and unemployment rate in each cell. This is the standard format from the BLS website. I've added a column for each table corresponding to the state abbreviation.

Second table has a large number of incidents, each incident is a row. Columns are various data about the incident, including state abbreviation and date. I want to make a vlookup (or whatever is more appropriate/efficient) that pulls the corresponding state unemployment for the appropriate date for each incident (150k+ in total) from the first worksheet.

I'm guessing I would need to reorganize the tables in the first worksheet so that each month/year combination was a row, or use some combination of "match" and "if" and the like. A little lazy, but it has been years since I messed with much Excel so I figured I'd start here. I really appreciate anyone's input.

Edit:

So I'm trying to nest multiple lookups, which can't be the intelligent way to do this (formula In 2nd, incident-based worksheet).

Innermost/first lookup: use state in incident worksheet: find all applicable years in 1st worksheet that only apply to this state (I'm returning a range of rows, after searching by row??  state is a column, as is year.  month is a row (first column header).

Middle/second lookup: use year in incident worksheet: find within returned range of years from above (a subset of rows), exact row, containing month Jan-Dec (remember that months are columns, ie column labels) for the appropriate State-Year pair.

Outermost lookup: use month in incident worksheet: find within returned range of months from second lookup, exact month (at this point, ideally this would be the exact unemployment rate).

Edited in: just trying to make it as clear as I can:

Worksheet 1) Unemployment Rates:

```
State  Year   Jan   Feb  Mar  Apr  etc
AK     1991    3.5  4.3    5  6.1   x       
AK     1992    3.1  4.1    x    x   x
TX     1991      x    x    x    x   x
TX     1992      x    x    x    x   x
VA     1993      x    x    x    x   x 
VA     1994      x    x    x    x   x
```

Worksheet 2) Incidents:

```
Exact Calendar Date  Year  State    xxx   xxx     etc  (unemp rate)
xx/xx/xxxx           xxxx     xx      x     x     x      ?????
xx/xx/xxxx           xxxx     xx      x     x     x      ?????
```

`=hlookup(month(b2),vlookup(c2,(vlookup(av2,[in first worksheet with unemp. rates, all states, in alphabetical order and first column]A2:a1174,[years in worksheet 1 that apply to this state, range is all years, but nested lookup means it will only look at the ones with the correct state abbreviation, right?]b2:b1174),[in the unemp rate worksheet, for the 1 row year/state combination that is returned, search among all months]$c$1:$n$1),*****)`

Trying to provide notes here to make the above more clear:

```
b2 = month in incident worksheet (#2 in my original post)
c2 = year in incident worksheet 
av2=state abbreviation in incident worksheet
```

So this is one question among many. Conceptually, at this point I wanted to have the last hlookup function search by month among the appropriate year/state row, and return the exact cell I want. But, it has become so convoluted I don't know how to reference the last returned value.

Thank you for any help!  Let me know if I can provide more clarity.

Answer (score 5):

Since all the rates are numbers, you could use `SUMIFS` to get the lookups with multiple conditions. The only thing that would be left would be to get the correct month, and you can get that using `INDEX` and `MATCH`:

```
=SUMIFS(INDEX('Unemp. Rates'!C:N, 0, MATCH(TEXT(B2,"mmm"),'Unemp. Rates'!$C$1:$N$1,0)), 'Unemp. Rates'!A:A, AV2, 'Unemp. Rates'!B:B, B2)
```

Evaluating the innermost to outermost:

- `TEXT(B2,"mmm")`: Gives the month in text of the date in B2. Let's say the month is January. `Jan` will be the result here.
- `MATCH("Jan",'Unemp. Rates'!$C$1:$N$1,0)`: Gives the number where `"Jan"` month is found. If it was `Jan`, you get `1` since it's the first cell.
- `INDEX('Unemp. Rates'!C:N, 0, 1)`: Returns the 1st column from `C:N` that is `C:C`. `0` means all the rows, and `1` is what was previously obtained. If it were `Feb`, there would have been `2` and the column would have been `D:D`.
- `SUMIFS(C:C, 'Unemp. Rates'!A:A, AV2, 'Unemp. Rates'!B:B, B2)`: returns the sum of values from the C column, provided the values in column A match the AV2 value (state), the values in column B match the B2 value (year).

I don't expect you to have more than one row with the same state *and* same year, so there's actually no 'SUM' taking place.

Comment: What does "Returns the 1st column from C:N that is C:C." mean, specifically the C:C??  This is just the last step to index the month for the column number, right?  I think I almost have it.

Comment: OK - so now I don't get any #NA, but I always get "0" returned.  Formula has been amended to: 


    =SUMIFS(INDEX([Unemp.xlsx]Sheet1!C:N, 0, MATCH(TEXT(MONTH(B2),"mmm"),[Unemp.xlsx]Sheet1!$C$1:$N$1,0)), [Unemp.xlsx]Sheet1!A:A, AU2, [Unemp.xlsx]Sheet1!B:B, C2)

It looks like it is never considering the conditions a match, so it sums nothing??

Comment: @arffarf Um, I really meant it to be `=TEXT('Date',"mmm")` so if the date was in another cell, you will have to change it. [Here's a spreadsheet sample](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1veqNNn6aOdja2U33fK7_4bQvU81MAAjrH6Zu8wHEtg8/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: yes I was able to change that no problem, and test it and it works fine.  the error appears to be somewhere else.

Comment: @arffarf If the problem is with duplicates, then you will have a higher rate that you should. One thing I hadn't thought about is: are you rates stored as text or as numbers? If they are stored as text, you will be getting 0. To convert all of them to number, put 1 somewhere in the sheet, copy, select all the rates, paste special > multiply (you can delete the 1 after that).

Comment: I believe the issue is in matching the state and year, although I'm not 100%.

Comment: @arffarf Can you perhaps take a snapshot of your UnEmp Rates table and let me see? Also, going to Formulas > Evaluate Formula might give some clues.

Comment: even better: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=8E72133687ABB879%21921  hope that works first time trying to share via onedrive  "cc" is UnemploymentRates ws

Comment: If you prefer to just handle a screengrab-How do I send you a message on here with it?  I can't post image in comments.

Comment: @arffarf Ohh I see. The year is actually stored as a date. You can either change the year column and put the formula `=YEAR(B2)` or change the `SUMIFS` so the last reference becomes `YEAR(C2)`.

Comment: NICE.  That actually occurred to me too and I dismissed it.  Thanks so much, learned a ton from this.

Comment: @arffarf Yea, dates are not equivalent to years :) Glad to have helped you ^^